# slider stripping out caption/excerpt line breaks

Tags: captions, line-breaks

I ran into an issue where the slider I was using (Wonderplugin) was stripping out paragraph and other formatting tags on captions/descriptions, though they were working on the actual images in Posts.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the very low-tech, but functional, fix of adding`&lt;p&gt;`  in place of an html paragraph tag. Worked like a charm.